# Why unable to delete a row from MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have this table below and the table has data:

```
CREATE TABLE `hede` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `added` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `mode` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `bid` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sent` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `bid` (`bid`),
    INDEX `sent` (`sent`)
)
ENGINE=ndbcluster
```

This is the data I want to delete

> SELECT * FROM hede WHERE bid = 123;

```
+-----+-----------------------------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id  | added                       | mode | bid  | sent                        |
+-----+-----------------------------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| 164 | 2016-03-07 09:57:21         |    0 | 123  | 2016-03-04 09:57:22         |
+-----+-----------------------------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

But whe I attempt to delete this row;

> DELETE FROM hede WHERE id = 164;

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Why I can't delete this data?

**P.S.**: There are other columns in the original table. Some reasons I can't expose whole rows, but I assure you that I couldn't exposed rows are has no relation to another table, or record.

Comment: How do you select `bid=1234` and get `bid = 882` ?

Comment: If you are querying using "Where bid = 1234" and get a row where bid is not 1234 then I would think you may possibly have a corrupted index, which could be the reason the delete does not work. Refer to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html) regarding checking and repairing indexes.

Comment: Just corrected misstype.

Comment: Try `DELETE..WHERE bid = 123` . What happens?

Comment: Does the row show up if you run `SELECT * FROM hede WHERE id = 164;` instead of `SELECT * FROM hede WHERE bid = 123;`? Is the row still there, despite the *rows affected* reported by MySQL? Are you running all the commands from the same session?

Comment: I think you have passed the id value as a foreign key in another table that means the id is used by another table thats why its not deleting.First you need to delete the entry from that table

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes it does show that row even if I run query with "id" or "bid" And yes, all commands executed in same session. Also the data is still there.

Comment: I ran your schema, added that data, and then could remove it using your command. Are there any triggers we should know about?

Comment: Try the same column and value SELECT and DELETE WHERE id=164

Comment: @sagi, Result is same.

Comment: @Mihai I try to represent that I can call data with 'bid' and 'id'.

Comment: @ChrisLear I need to check it. You may has a point.

Comment: What engine is the table? Could it be that your table is corrupt?

Comment: @大丈夫 The engine of the table is `ndbcluster`, May be the ROW corrupted but table is working. I can write and delete any other rows.

Comment: @SencerH. What is the replication setup? Simple Master > Slave?

Comment: @大丈夫 I'dont know about setup of the cluster.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting from

Comment: Can you insert a record with an id of 164?

Comment: Is this on a production? If not could you make a backup of the table and execute truncate on the table.

Comment: Unforunately, it's on production and I can't try to insert record for replacing current data or truncate.

Comment: There is not much we can do. I believe your table is corrupt. To repair your table you can execute `REPAIR TABLE hede`. However this command can make the server lose synchronization with the master or the slave servers. It is recommended to stop the synchronization before executing this command.

Answer (score -1):

May quote the value like:

```
DELETE FROM hede WHERE id = '164'
```

---

- ``` `` ``` ticks are for identifying database, table and column names
- `''` or `" "` quotes are for values

Comment: Except that in this case, quoting is optional. I was able to delete the row in mysql using exactly the code in the OP's question, with no quotes.

Comment: No, numbers should not be quoted. Although the DBMS will be able to cast the string to a number, there are scenarios where this will prevent use of an index on the column due to a type mismatch (though not in this case).

Comment: @ChrisLear I know quoting is optional. But I have experiences that unquoted values didn't work. It's just a suggestion that 'may' work for him. I'm still thinking of what the OP's real problem.

Comment: @symcbean Oh okay. I think that part is what I still don't know. Thanks for mentioning.